# How do I remove duplicate objects in an array by field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'kitten'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'kitten'
},{
  id: 3,
  name: 'cat
}]
```

How do I remove the second kitten? Sorting into an array of names doesn't work, because I can't know if I am deleting `id` 1 or or `id` 2. So, I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you get the array from somewhere or you create it yourself? Because if you create it yourself it would be wise to check for duplicates before insertion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: I get it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the lodash library.
You could use the [uniq](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq)

```
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'kitten'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'kitten'
},{
  id: 3,
  name: 'cat'
}];


var asd = _.uniq(array,'name');

console.log(asd);
```

Gives an output:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'kitten' }, { id: 3, name: 'cat' } ]
```

as it written in the documentation "only the first occurence of each element is kept".

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too. The issue is that I need to find the ID of the excluded item in order to delete it through an API. Not sure how to get that. Perhaps a set function that shows me the difference?

Comment: yes you could do that. use the difference function of lodash, doing the following


var asd = _.uniq(array,'name');

console.log(asd);


var dif = _.difference(array,asd);
console.log(dif);

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional hash-map to store names found so far. When you process a next object if it's name is already in the hash-map it is a duplicate and you can remove it.

```
var duplicates = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length) {
    var obj = array[i];

    if (! duplicates[obj.name]) {
        duplicates[obj.name] = 1;
        i++;
    } else {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example piece of code I could look at, for that? I know that this is possible in other languages, I just haven't encountered hash maps before in JS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var arr =[{
      id: 1,
      name: 'kitten'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'kitten'
    },{
      id: 3,
      name: 'cat'
    }];
    var results = [];
    var idsSeen = {}, idSeenValue = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length, name; i < len; ++i) {
        name = arr[i].name;
        if (idsSeen[name] !== idSeenValue) {
            results.push(arr[i]);
            idsSeen[name] = idSeenValue;
        }
    }
    console.log(results);
```